# Trying to style the FA icon fab -fa-github in CSS Doesn't Work

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm trying to style the FA icon fab fa-github in CSS. While the icon shows, no styling shows/changes to the icon, Here's what I'm using. Thank you.

**HTML**

```
<i class="fab fa-github"></i>
```

**CSS**

```
.fa-github {
    color: rgb(255, 81, 0);
    font-size: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the `.fab` class to your css? I.e. `.fab.fa-github {...`

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I believe you only need the class name and not the full font awesome name that's displayed to use/style font awesome icons with CSS (could be wrong). The issue on my end was a misplaced CSS file in wrong folder directory causing the stylesheet itself to not display.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the correct cdn link for fontawesome because everything is working just fine
here:

```css
.fa-github {
    color: rgb(255, 81, 0);
    font-size: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />


<i class="fab fa-github"></i>
```

Comment: It is working now thank you for the reply. The issue was my contact.css sheet was added in the html folder and not in css folder (wrong directory) My apologizes. Got it all sorted once I added the contact.css sheet in correct folder.

Comment: @THC no worries man it happens all the time, happy coding :)